# Toggle side menu with Icons in Ionic 4

Tags: css, ionic4, angular8, sidenav, ion-menu

In my application built in Ionic 4 and Angular 8 PWA, I am need of a side menu(ion-menu) that toggles to show only icons on collapse and  menu text on expand in browser. I am able to achieve this in Ionic 3. But find it difficult in Ionic 4. 
Is there any online resource available, request to provide me links to the available sources.
Or is it advised to use angular sidebar instead of ion-menu?

Comment: can you share your code for Ionic 3 and what’s not working in ionic 4?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu